Taking a scene from a video I made
I took photos and video of a place that I liked, to use it in my website. I now see that the video scenes look better than the photos. May be due to resolution, I am not expert. My question is, how can I take a scene from my video by keeping its resolution at the same time? I am not talking about taking simply screenshot because in that case the resolution is lost.
And if I do this, and take and use a scene from the video I made as a photo, this is exactly the same as owning copyright of a photo I made right?

Videos are almost without exception captured at a significantly lower resolution than still images. For whatever reason your video looks better, it is very unlikely because of better resolution. You must also be aware, that if you extract single frames from a video recording, you are much more likely to see artifacts in the extracted frame, which are not noticable when playing the video. But, give it a try, perhaps you achieve what you are expecting.

I took my video with the highest resolution possible in my camera and highest frame per second

In principle, recording a video is really nothing much different to recording a bunch of photos - recorded in very quick succession, and originally intended to be displayed in very quick succession - but that isn't obligatory.

@osullic in practice, if you recorded the photos in the same quality as you record the regular photos, you would have enough storage for maybe 30s of video.

@OrangeDog My point relates to the idea of taking a frame from a video and whether it's equally "valid" as a photograph, from the point of view of copyright. I don't quite see what your point relates to, in terms of the question being asked here.

@osullic there are two separate questions. You didn't make clear which you were talking about.

Recording video at the highest resolution but lowest FPS would make more sense if trying to get stills off it

@ChrisH Disagree. See e.g. https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2016/08/11/sports/olympics/simone-biles-winning-moves.html Now I'm not claiming the photographer(s) shot video here, and extracted individual frames as photos...but if you find yourself in a situation where extracting frames from video is your only recourse, then for some situations, it's better to have as many frames as possible to choose from.

@osullic we can both be right in different contexts.  For fast motion, you're more likely to be right - get the perfect moment and avoiding motion blur within a frame.  The question's "of a place I liked" didn't suggest that to me, instead suggesting a situation where a lower framerate would give the option for longer exposure times and lower gain to reduce image noise.  "Place" is vague enough that light levels could be low, and noise in the dark regions of a grabbed frame is quite striking on a photo.

@osullic, Re, "video is really nothing much different to...a bunch of photos recorded in very quick succession." Except, maybe in one respect: When we photograph a moving object, we often choose a fast shutter speed to "freeze" the motion. But, video usually is shot with a shutter speed that is close to the frame rate because the resulting motion blur looks more "natural" than if a fast shutter were used.

@Ohm'sLawman as before, this is kind of irrelevant in terms of my point. Sure there are lots of different creative decisions we can take with both stills and video... My point relates to the conceptual notion of taking a frame from a video and using it as a photo. Is this "valid" as a photo? I argue yes of course. Whether the settings used were optimal or not has nothing to do with it.

You can use for example ffmpeg program to extract the image. The command will be something like:
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:04 -i input.mp4 -frames:v 1 screenshot.png

where 00:01:04 is the moment when you want to extract the image, -frames:v 1 define to extract one frame. The rest is self-explained.
And yes, the image extracted will inherit the copyright, so if you take the video you own the copyright of image

While I love FFmpeg, I wouldn't use it for this task. Personally I'd probably use Avidemux - I think it's easier to use an application with a graphical user interface so you can step through the video frame by frame - especially because there are simply so many frames to choose from.

@osullic, good point, but as I do not use Avidemux, will prefer VLC :)

I forget if FFmpeg will default to seeking to an I-frame (keyframe) near the selected -ss.  I think so, unless you use an accurate-seek option to make it decode from the last keyframe to the frame with the exact timestamp you specify.  In this case you probably want an I-frame because they're higher quality.  Unless the scene is moving and the image you want is only present as a P or B frame.  Avidemux will show you frame types and has options to seek to the next or previous keyframe, so I'd second @osullic's recommendation.  https://mpv.io/ can also do that; hit s for screenshot.

VLC can snap single frames using a key command [default Cmd/Opt/S on Mac, idk on Win].
It's obviously easier to get the correct frame in pause. You can advance one frame at a time using the ] key.

QtHotkeys - VideoLAN Wiki

@osullic - thanks. A lot of those are very different from the Mac defaults.

Unfortunately, VLC doesn't support frame-stepping backwards, so it can be a bit painful if you find you've stepped a little too far. I ended up switching to mpv for a similar purpose; by default it assigns , and . to frame-stepping backwards and forwards respectively.

I have jump back set to just one second on the Mac I use this feature on most frequently., but you\re right a one frame back would be more useful.
